# How can I generate strings that satisfy some restrictions?

Tags: string, constraints

Can anyone give me a hand with techniques to generate strings that satisfy certain restrictions.

For example, say I need to generate strings s and t such that

```
      length(s) < length(t)
      length(t) > 12
      t contains at least 3 capital letters
and   s contains a 2
```

And **I don't mean this particular example but some generic techniques to generate strings that satisfy certain conditions**.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp

Comment: Smells like homework, is this homework?

Comment: related, from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100803/how-can-i-generate-integers-that-satisfy-some-restrictions

Comment: Not homework. I just need to generate strings and integers satisfying some conditions and haven't found any better techniques than Boundary value analysis and equivalence partitioning. Those don't seem enough, so I'm asking to know if someone with more experience in this matters can guide my research.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [Random string that matches a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp)

for good discussion and ideas.
Thanks!
Manuel